# How can i style differently a link in a div adding a class to it?

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I have multiple `div`s inside a `div` with a class of `.grid`. Inside those `div`s i have a link in each.  I styled those links by using the selector `.grid div a`. After that i added another link in each `div`, and gave it a class `.name` and selected it using `.grid div .name`. The problem is that these new links with class name are affected by the cascade. Why is that happening? `.grid div .name` selector is more specific right?
This is my CSS
This is for making a div into a clickable link

```
.grid div a
{
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top:0;
left:0;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 1;
}
This is the style for the other links
.grid div.name
{
position: absolute;
height: 20px;
width: 120px;
font-family: lato;
color:  #424242;
}
```

[image: Click for image]

Comment: Can you add your code or jsfiddle link?

Comment: I added the code. Thanks

Comment: div a:nth-child(1){ color:green;} you can try like this

Comment: Given that you tagged this with the `css-specificity` tag, you've pretty much answered your own question but, just in case, you should read up on specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 1):

> This is the style for the other links
>
> `.grid div.name`

## No, it isn't!

This would be:

```
.grid div a.name
```

or

```
.grid div .name
```

```css
.grid div a.name {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <a href="#1">First Link</a>
    <a href="#2" class="name">Name Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your current selector selects divs with a class of name because there is no *"space"* between the element type and the class.

Comment: Then you need to provide a demo of you HTML and CSS.

Comment: So what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to do a clickable article grid. For that i created a link inside the div, set its height and width to 100%, so its a div that acts as a link. But inside that div i have another link, and need to style that separately but it inherits the styling for the div sized links.

Comment: The second link is the article authors name. I want to link the name to a page with all that authors articles.

Comment: So change the selector for the first link so those style are only applied to THAT link. Give it a class or something and use that, then the generic styles  won't apply to **all** links.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting it to work the other way around. Both the links are selected by the CSS of `.grid div a`.

If there are styles that you want to NOT affect the `.grid div a.name` selectors then change your CSS in that second definition to re-override them back to what you want them to be.

e.g if the first one has font-size: 2em, change the .name definition to alter it back to font-size: 1em.

Comment: Ok.. But isnt the presence of 2 class selector be enough to override the first styling?

Comment: The first one says "style all links on this page" the second one says "style all links on this page IF they've got a class of name". Any conflicts will be won by the .name selector as it is more specific.

However, as mentioned in another answer, check your .name is against the a link rather than the div.

Comment: I think you need to post your HTML as well as your CSS, because that's different to the code you entered in your question above.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/roppazvan/fq44cpcb/#&togetherjs=72HDywO1Me

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this nth child concept:

```
div a:nth-child(1){color:green;}
```